# Is there a maximum size for the number of accounts that a transaction can refer to?

Tags: arrays, layout, transactions, account, solana

I can't quite find in [the docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#account-addresses-format) whether there is a predefined limit on the size/length of accounts array included in each transaction.

Is it only limited by the 1232 bytes limit on the whole transaction itself or is it something more particular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now it is limited by the 1232 bytes on the whole transaction.